# Get full class name of a class that starts with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div with many different classes. I know that I can select the div with starts with `$('div[class^=class]')` but I want to get the full class name if I know what it starts with. I am using **Bootstrap**, and the columns begin with **col-lg-** so for each div that has class `$('div[class^=col-lg-]')` **I want to know the rest of that class (example col-lg-4), or the number in this case**.

```
$('[class^col-lg-]').each(function(){

  var block = {};
  block.width = ___;

});
```

Comment: You can get the classes with `$(this).attr('class')` and apply a regex on string result.

Comment: So you want to find every element whose class "*starts with*" the string `"col-lg-"` or has any class that begins with `"col-lg-"`?

Comment: @triplethreat77 please check my demo and undo your downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$(this).attr('class')`

```
    $(function(){
$("div[class^='col-lg-']").each(function(){
       var fullclassname= $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
       return v.indexOf('col-lg-') === 0;
   }).join();
    alert(fullclassname);
    });
    });
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/on3qazpx/)

or you could also use

```
$(this).prop("class")
```

Comment: This will not work, because **I HAVE MULTIPLE CLASSES**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[class^=col-lg-]').each(function(){
  var classNames= $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  var requiredClass;
  for(var i=0;i<classNames.length;i++)
 {
   if(classNames[i].match('col-lg-')){
     requiredClass=classNames[i];
     break;
     }
 }
  var block = {};
  block.width = ___;

});
```